# How to get function name, when substitute returns an expression

Tags: r, function, expression

I am using Shiny selectInput, where functions' names are matched with match.fun and passed to another function. e.g. One can choose between mean, median, sum etc. and passed like this:
`someFunction(summary.fun = match.fun(input$summary_fun))`

When I try to recover the name of the function within the function with `substitute(summary.fun)`, which returns `match.fun(input$summary_fun)`.

I can pass this function to other functions such as `aggregate(..., FUN = summary.fun)`, and everything works fine.

I would like to retrieve the function name as "mean", "median", "sum" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't in that way, not easily. From [`?match.fun`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/match.fun):

> *Value: A function matching 'FUN'...*

To me this means it returns the function itself, not a label or name or pointer to that function.

To increase the likelihood that you can get a usable "character function name" as well as the actual function body, try

```r
someFunction <- function(summary.fun, ...) {
  if (is.character(summary.fun)) {
    funcname <- summary.fun
    realfunc <- match.fun(summary.fun)
  } else if (is.function(summary.fun)) {
    funcname <- deparse(substitute(summary.fun))
    realfunc <- summary.fun
  }
  # ...
}
quux <- reactive({
  req(try(match.fun(input$summary_fun)))
  someFunction(summary.fun = input$summary_fun, ...)
})
```

The use of `req(try(match.fun(input$summary_fun)))` means that the reactive block will not fire if the `input$summary_fun` does not match a known function name. (It may not be completely necessary in your context, over to you.) (The use of `try` is because `req` triggers "not-truthy" on *an object of class '"try-error"'* (from `?req`), which will happen if `input$summary_fun` does not reflect a known function.)

Comment: Yes, I did it in that way eventually (as a workaround). I was wondering, if I was missing something. If there are no answers proving otherwise, I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: One problem is that if you `deparse(substitute(summary.fun))`, you're likely to see `match.fun(input$summary_fun)`, because that's what was provided to the called function. For consistency in R, though I'd think you would delay converting to a function to as late as possible; for instance, `do.call` and `aggregate` both accept an anonymous function (`function(x, ...) {...}`), a named function (`mean`), and the character representation of the function (`"mean"`). That's just those two functions, I believe many others do that as well. Having this logic in `someFunction` "makes sense" to me.